# What "Pastie" alternatives are there? (installable)

Tags: ruby, ramaze, pastie, rapaste

I want to install a "pastie" in our local intranet. What are the alternatives to **[RaPaste](http://p.ramaze.net)** and [pastie.org](http://pastie.org)? (the latter can't even be installed locally b/c it doesn't seem to be open source?)

**Edit**: Doesn't have to be Ruby btw.

**Edit**: What I mean with pastie is an app where you can share source code pastes instead of pasting it in an irc chat.

Comment: You may want to edit the title to indicate that you want to install pastie software, not just go to a URL and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is for instance [LodgeIt](http://dev.pocoo.org/projects/lodgeit/) by the Pocoo guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your request isn't very clear. Starting by defining what are "pasties" in your mind might help (I knew pasties from deviantART, which are very different beasts...). I had to go to the indicated sites to have an idea.
It isn't clear either if it must be Ruby only or not (I see only a tag, no clear requirement).

I know the old and reputed pastebin.org, [its (PHP) source](http://blog.dixo.net/downloads/) is available.